# How to merge only a specific field of different rows with awk

Tags: awk, text, columnsorting

data.file

```
Istanbul;J;TK;13;OK
London;C;EN;28;OK
London;K;EN;32;OK
Paris;A;FR;30;OK
Paris;B;FR;40;OK
Zurich;G;DE;99;OK
Zurich;H;DE;33;OK
Zurich;G;DE;82;OK
```

Expected output:

```
Istanbul;J;TK;13;OK
London;C-K;EN;28-32;OK
Paris;A-B;FR;30-40;OK
Zurich;G-H;DE;33-82-99;OK
```

First field of every row is the condition, if this field is duplicated then merge fields 2 and 4, in field 5 just use the first occurrence.

<del>**Update**: another condition is that fields 2 and 4 have to be sorted and repeated data deleted, as in the case of field 2 of Zurich.</del>

The code I have so far is that in fields 2 and 4 data has to be sorted and repetitions deleted, as for Zurich...

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=';' '{getline nx; j=split (nx, Ax); for (i=1;i<=j;i++) $i=$i Ax[i]}1' data.file
```

Which obviously is not working as expected, this is what awfully gives back....

```
ParisParis;AB;FRFR;3040;OKOK
LondonLondon;CK;ENEN;2832;OKOK
IstanbulZurich;JZ;TKDE;1382;OKOK
ZurichZurich;GH;DEDE;9933;OKOK
```

Comment: Now, I have sorted... and yes 3rd field will be repeated along the rows with the same city.

Comment: Yes, it does... G-H while in source data is G-H-G... anyway, I'm taking out this part as you suggested...

Comment: ahh, sorry, you are right, I was focused in 2nd field only, my apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for `sorted_in`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
$1 != prev {
    if ( NR>1 ) {
        prt()
    }
    prev = $1
    delete vals
}
{
    for ( fldNr=1; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++ ) {
        vals[fldNr][$fldNr]
    }
}
END { prt() }

function prt(           fldNr,val,sep) {
    for ( fldNr=1; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++ ) {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_" (fldNr==4 ? "num" : "str") "_asc"
        sep = ""
        for ( val in vals[fldNr] ) {
            printf "%s%s", sep, val
            sep = "-"
        }
        printf "%s", (fldNr<NF ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk data.file
Istanbul;J;TK;13;OK
London;C-K;EN;28-32;OK
Paris;A-B;FR;30-40;OK
Zurich;G-H;DE;33-82-99;OK
```

Comment: you're a big awk sensei... all my gratitude to you...

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- all rows for a given city will show up on contiguous lines so as soon as we see a 'new' city we can go ahead and print the 'old' city data to stdout

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
function printline() {
    if (flds[1]) {                                    # if the previous city is non-blank then ...
       for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)                            # loop through list of fields and ...
           printf "%s%s", (i==1 ? "" : OFS), flds[i]  # print to stdout
       print ""                                       # terminate the printf output with a linefeed
    }
    delete flds                                       # delete all data for the previous city
}
BEGIN         { FS=OFS=";" }
$1 != flds[1] { printline()                           # if this is a new city then print the previous city and then ...
                for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)                   # capture all of the current fields
                    flds[i]=$i
                next
              }
              { for (i=2;i<NF;i=i+2)                  # if this is a repeat city then process the 2nd and 4th fields by ...
                    flds[i]=flds[i] "-" $i            # appending the current values to the previous value(s)
              }
END           { printline() }                         # print the last city
' data.file
```

This generates:

```
Istanbul;J;TK;13;OK
London;C-K;EN;28-32;OK
Paris;A-B;FR;30-40;OK
Zurich;G-H-Z;DE;99-33-82;OK
```

Comment: Wow, it works as a charm!! I add a further detail in the question that I have realized now checking my data... sorry

Comment: @AndrésChandía your latest changes/additions are enough to change the overall design of the current answer; I'd suggest you rollback the latest edit to your question, take this answer and see if you can modify it to address the new changes/additions and if you have any issues then ask a new question; if you ask a new question I'd suggest you also provide your `awk` version (ie, output from `awk --version`) as I'm thinking `GNU awk` has support for multi-dimensional arrays and in-memory sorting of said arrays, both of which could be of use in your new question

Comment: Thanks @markp-fuso, I'll do it, I am already dealing separately in sorting the resulting fields... thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F';' '
    BEGIN{OFS=";"}
    {
        a[$1][2][$2]; a[$1][3]=$3;  a[$1][4][$4]; a[$1][5]=$5;
    } 
    END{
        for (i in a){ 
            n = asorti(a[i][2], a2)
            for (x=n; x>0; x--) o2 = sprintf("%s-%s", a2[x],o2) 
            n = asorti(a[i][4], a4)
            for (x=n; x>0; x--) o4 = sprintf("%s-%s", a4[x],o4) 
            print i, substr(o2,1,length(o2)-1), a[i][3],substr(o4,1,length(o4)-1), a[i][5]
            o2=o4=""
        }
    }' file|sort

Istanbul;J;TK;13;OK
London;C-K;EN;28-32;OK
Paris;A-B;FR;30-40;OK
Zurich;G-H;DE;33-82-99;OK
```